# TreeView Recursion in C# load from SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql, wpf, treeview

I have one table in SQL Server and i want load it to treeview in WPF

Category ID Name ParentID
1   Clothing    0
2   Entertainment   0
3   Taxes   ... 1
4   Phone   ... 2
5   Rent    ... 3
6   Travel  ... 1
7   Salary  ... 2
8   ABC ... 3
9   Gift    ... 5
10  Cool    ... 1
11  Income  ... 4
12  Tower   ... 6

My code in C#:

```
private void LoadTreeView()
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(s);
        SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Category", con);
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(comm);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds);
        DataTable dt = ds.Tables[0];
        TreeViewItem tvi = new TreeViewItem();
        AddNode(tvi, dt, 0);
        con.Close();
    }

private void AddNode(TreeViewItem tvi, DataTable dt, int node)
    {
        foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
        {
            if ((int)row["ParentID"] == 0)
            {
                tvi = new TreeViewItem();
                tvi.Header = row["Name"];
                treeView.Items.Add(tvi);
                DataTable dtb = dt;
                node = (int)row["CategoryID"];
                dtb.Rows.Remove(row);
                AddNode(tvi, dtb, node);
            }
            else
            {
                int i = 0;

                foreach (DataRow r in dt.Rows)
                {
                    i++;
                    if ((int)r["ParentID"] == node)
                    {
                        TreeViewItem tvi2 = new TreeViewItem();
                        tvi2.Header = r["Name"];
                        tvi.Items.Add(tvi2);
                        DataTable dtb = dt;
                        node = (int)r["CategoryID"];
                        dtb.Rows.Remove(r);
                        if (dtb.Rows.Count == 0)
                            return;
                        AddNode(tvi2, dtb, node);
                    }
                    if (i == dt.Rows.Count)
                        return;
                }
            }
            if (dt.Rows.Count == 0)
                return;
        }
    }
```

But got error when run in second foreach
An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Data.dll

Additional information: Collection was modified; enumeration operation might not execute.

How can I fix it?

EDIT: I fixed it already.

```
private void AddNode(TreeViewItem tvi, DataTable dt, int node)
    {
        foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
        {
            if ((int)row["ParentID"] != 0 && (int)row["ParentID"] == node)
            {
                TreeViewItem tvi2 = new TreeViewItem();
                tvi2.Header = row["Name"];
                tvi.Items.Add(tvi2);
                DataTable dt2 = dt.Copy();
                int i = 0;
                for (i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
                {
                    if (row["CategoryID"] == dt.Rows[i]["CategoryID"])
                        break;
                }
                if (dt2.Rows.Count == 1)
                    return;
                dt2.Rows.RemoveAt(i);
                AddNode(tvi2, dt2, (int)row["CategoryID"]);
            }
            else if ((int)row["ParentID"] == 0 && node == 0)
            {
                tvi = new TreeViewItem();
                tvi.Header = row["Name"];
                treeView.Items.Add(tvi);
                DataTable dt2 = dt.Copy();
                int i = 0;
                for (i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
                {
                    if ((int)row["CategoryID"] == (int)dt.Rows[i]["CategoryID"])
                        break;
                }
                if (dt2.Rows.Count == 1)
                    return;
                dt2.Rows.RemoveAt(i);
                AddNode(tvi, dt2, (int)row["CategoryID"]);
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: Please elaborate on the error you are receiving.

Comment: Edit error details. Thank you for your concern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are modifying the datatable you are operating on inside the loop of dt.Rows.

When you say

```
DataTable dtb = dt;
```

it is creating another link to the same table, it is not creating a new table. Therefore, when you modify dtb, you are also modifying dt (essentially dt and dtb are two names for the same table.)

Since the table is fairly small, you may be able to get away with

```
DataTable dtb = dt.Clone();
```

This will make a copy of the table, instead of just an alias to the same table.

However, I do not see why you are removing a row from dtb in the first place. Since you are locally scoping it, and not using the table again within the scope, it seems a pointless operation. Since dtb is in the original code just an alias, you can do everything you use dtb for on dt with exactly the same result.